# remove all empty values from url

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove all empty values from an url:

```
var s="value1=a&value2=&value3=b&value4=c&value5=";
s = s.replace(...???...);
alert(s);
```

Expected output:

```
value1=a&value3=b&value4=c
```

I only need the query part of the URL to be taken into account.

Comment: Using JS or PHP? (Should the preg-replace tag be removed?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this:

```
s = s.replace(/[^=&]+=(&|$)/g,"").replace(/&$/,"");
```

That is, remove groups of one or more non-equals/non-ampersand characters that are followed by an equals sign and ampersand or end of string. Then remove any leftover trailing ampersand.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pKHzr/

Comment: This will strip the everything from the left of the URL if the first parameter is empty, I think this should be updated to: s = s.replace(/[^?=&]+=(&|$)/g,"").replace(/&$/,"");

Comment: @KeithTurkowski - The question said "I only need the query part of the URL to be taken into account."

Answer (score 4):

```
s = s.replace(/[^?=&]+=(&|$)/g,"").replace(/&$/,"");
```

Added a '?' to nnnnnn's answer to fix the issue where the first parameter is empty in a full URL.

Comment: Thank you. But in your solution the "?" mark still exists. Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: @Ulvi I don't understand your comment

Comment: or if you need remove empty or zero(...&param1=0...) parameters: `s = s.replace(/[^?=&]+=(0&|0|&|$)/g,"").replace(/&$/,"");`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var s="value1=a&value2=&value3=b&value4=c&value5=";
var tmp = s.split('&')
var newS = '';
for(var i in a) {
    var t = a[i];
    if(t[t.length - 1] !== '=') {
        newS += t + '&';
    }
}

if(newS[newS.length - 1] === '&') {
    newS = newS.substr(0, newS.length - 1);
}
console.log(newS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any solution to do that with one `Regex` expression.

But you could loop through your string and construct a new result string : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/3/

```
var s="value1=a&value2=&value3=b&value4=c&value5=";
var tmpArray = s.split('&');
var final = '';

for(var i=0 ; i<tmpArray.length ; i++)
        if(tmpArray[i].split('=')[1] != '')
             final += tmpArray[i] + '&';

final = final.substr(0,final.length-1)

alert(final)
```

Answer (score -1):

Where do you take all the values?
I suggest using an array:

```
function getValues(str){
var values = [];
var s = str.split('&');

for(var val in s){//source is a
    var split = val.split('=');
    if(split [1] != '' && split [1] != null){
        values.push(val);
    }
}

return values.join('&');
}
```