# Remove an empty query string from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I defined a query string `catid` as:

```
mydomain.com/?catid=
```

How to remove `?catid` in my url if it's empty please?

Comment: Can you add some code? Otherwise the answer to your question is "press backslash until that part is deleted".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove all empty values from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624275/remove-all-empty-values-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

The code from the very similar question from Jerome Brunel isn't working with your particular request.

```
var arr=['mydomain.com/?catid=','mydomain.com/?catid=1&id1=','mydomain.com/?catid=&id=1','mydomain.com/?catid=&id=','mydomain.com/?catid=&id=&id2=','mydomain.com/?catid=&id=1&id2=&id3=1&id4=&id5=1&id6=2'];
function removeEmptyQueryParameters(s) {
    return s.replace(/([\?&])([^=]+=($|&))+/g,'$1').replace(/[\?&]$/g,'');
}
arr.forEach(function(s) {
    console.log(s,removeEmptyQueryParameters(s));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's will be the most semantically-correct way:

```
url = 'mydomain.com/?catid='
url = url.split('?')
if (url.length > 1) {
    params = url[1].split('&');
    params = params.map(function(e){ return e.split('='); });
    params = params.filter(function(e){ return (e.length > 1) && (e[1].length > 0); });
    url = url[0];
    if (params.length > 0) {
        url += '?' + params.map(function(e){ return e.join('='); }).join('&');
    }
} else {
    url = url[0];
}
```